# Emitting socket.io messages from plain node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a requirement, where I need to emit socket.io message before my node server invokes rest service on backend to socket server from plain node.js server. I try to visualize what I am trying to do:

```
Client(sends data) --> 
       |->Node.js server (sends data to socket.io server --> Backend rest service
                  |->-- socket.io server
```

For this I have tried this in my plain node server.js

```
var io = require('./socket.io.js');

http.createServer(function(request,response) {
   var restUrl; //Data I am getting from request

   //Socket.io server information
   var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '3000'
    };

   var socket = io.connect(options);
    socket.on('connect', function () {
         socket.send(restUrl);
     });
}
```

But it's not working, giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'port' of undefined
at Socket.isXDomain (E:\Pradeep\BaaS\socket.io.js:1877:31)
at Socket.handshake (E:\Pradeep\BaaS\socket.io.js:1627:14)
at Socket.connect (E:\Pradeep\BaaS\socket.io.js:1699:10)
```

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong? Basically I am trying to monitor real time activity of my node server. Any guidance or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is socket.io client in your node.js server. Get the module `npm install socket.io-client` and then use following example -

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var connected = 0;

var socket = io.connect('localhost', {
  port: 3000
});

socket.on('connect', function(){
  console.log("connected");
  connected = 1;
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if(connected == 1)
    socket.emit('info', {my:'data'});
}).listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is totally wrong way of setting up socket.io for node.js.
The correct way is as follow:

```
    var app = require('express').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Source: http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Hi, I am not setting up server, but trying to emit a message to socket.io server from node.js server.

Comment: the above code does emit a message. read the documentation here: [link]http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Yes it does emit, but it's a socket server, I have that code. I want to call socket.io from plain Node.js server.